# Get selected text when receive shared data in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, share, uwp

have question about windows phone (UWP) app. Now we have opportunity to receive data if you subscribing for share data. So, user can click share page in IE on windows phone and send this page to facebook app or our app.

My question - is it possible to get selected text on page that user want to share?

```
if (this.shareOperation.Data.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Html))
{
 string htmlFormat = await shareOperation.Data.GetHtmlFormatAsync();
}
```

I saw this example, but htmlFormat variable in most cases does not contains selected text.

Is it possible to catch somehow selected text when you receive data into your app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Selected text is something that managed by the browser and it isn't reflected in the HTML.